# Font size defaulted to Arail 10 in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

When the reports are exported to Excel, the font size is always **Arial 10**. I have checked **Export Object Formatting** option in Report export options, but it didn't help. The report has **Times New Roman 9**.

Can anyone please help me find the configuration to preserve the font size.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just tested exporting myself and when you go to File>Export>Click on Report Export Options

Select one of the Excel Formats that say "Data Only." 
Click ok and then check mark (in the bottom section) Export Object Formatting. This should keep all the colors, bold, underline, everything that you have done.

Now go to File>Export>Export Report and choose the same "Data Only" one you chose before. Click OK and make sure the check mark stuck. Click OK again, and save file where you would like. I hope this helps :-)

Comment: If this does work for you, please like my answer. Thanks!